# why is len so much more efficient on DataFrame than on underlying numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've noticed that using `len` on a DataFrame is far quicker than using `len` on the underlying numpy array.  I don't understand why.  Accessing the same information via `shape` isn't any help either.  This is more relevant as I try to get at the number of columns and number of rows.  I was always debating which method to use.

I put together the following experiment and it's very clear that I will be using `len` on the dataframe.  But can someone explain why?

```
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ns = np.power(10, np.arange(6))
results = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=ns,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [['len', 'len(values)', 'shape'],
         ns]))
dfs = {(n, m): pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n, m))) for n in ns for m in ns}

for n, m in dfs.keys():
    df = dfs[(n, m)]
    results.loc[('len', n), m] = timeit('len(df)', 'from __main__ import df', number=10000)
    results.loc[('len(values)', n), m] = timeit('len(df.values)', 'from __main__ import df', number=10000)
    results.loc[('shape', n), m] = timeit('df.values.shape', 'from __main__ import df', number=10000)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(9, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, (m, col) in enumerate(results.iteritems()):
    r, c = i // 3, i % 3
    col.unstack(0).plot.bar(ax=axes[r, c], title=m)
```

[image]

Comment: You should find that a fourth option `df.shape` should take about double the time of `len(df)`.

Comment: May be it isn't the `len` or `shape` that's reletively slow bu the `.values` step.  Fetching the `len` or `shape` of an existing numpy array should be fast, since those are just attributes of the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From looking at the various methods, the main reason is that **constructing the numpy array `df.values` takes the lion's share of the time**.

---

#### `len(df)` and `df.shape`

These two are fast because they are essentially

```
len(df.index._data)
```

and

```
(len(df.index._data), len(df.columns._data))
```

where `_data` is a `numpy.ndarray`.  Thus, using `df.shape` should be half as fast as `len(df)` because it's finding the length of both `df.index` and `df.columns` (both of type `pd.Index`)

---

#### `len(df.values)` and `df.values.shape`

Let's say you had already extracted `vals = df.values`.  Then

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 10), columns=range(10))

In [2]: vals = df.values

In [3]: %timeit len(vals)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 35.4 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit vals.shape
10000000 loops, best of 3: 51.7 ns per loop
```

Compared to:

```
In [5]: %timeit len(df.values)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.55 µs per loop
```

So the bottleneck is not `len` but how `df.values` is constructed. If you examine `pandas.DataFrame.values()`, you'll find the (roughly equivalent) methods:

```
def values(self):
    return self.as_matrix()

def as_matrix(self, columns=None):
    self._consolidate_inplace()
    if self._AXIS_REVERSED:
        return self._data.as_matrix(columns).T

    if len(self._data.blocks) == 0:
        return np.empty(self._data.shape, dtype=float)

    if columns is not None:
        mgr = self._data.reindex_axis(columns, axis=0)
    else:
        mgr = self._data

    if self._data._is_single_block or not self._data.is_mixed_type:
        return mgr.blocks[0].get_values()
    else:
        dtype = _interleaved_dtype(self.blocks)
        result = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=dtype)
        if result.shape[0] == 0:
            return result

        itemmask = np.zeros(self.shape[0])
        for blk in self.blocks:
            rl = blk.mgr_locs
            result[rl.indexer] = blk.get_values(dtype)
            itemmask[rl.indexer] = 1

        # vvv here is your final array assuming you actually have data
        return result 

def _consolidate_inplace(self):
    def f():
        if self._data.is_consolidated():
            return self._data

        bm = self._data.__class__(self._data.blocks, self._data.axes)
        bm._is_consolidated = False
        bm._consolidate_inplace()
        return bm
    self._protect_consolidate(f)

def _protect_consolidate(self, f):
    blocks_before = len(self._data.blocks)
    result = f()
    if len(self._data.blocks) != blocks_before:
        if i is not None:
            self._item_cache.pop(i, None)
        else:
            self._item_cache.clear()
    return result
```

Note that `df._data` is a `pandas.core.internals.BlockManager`, not a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Good to know! I'd (wrongly) assumed that `df._data` would lead to an `ndarray`.

Comment: @RandyC Yeah so did I until I looked through the source just now.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `__len__` for `pd.DataFrame`, they actually just call `len(df.index)`: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L770

For a `RangeIndex`, this is a really fast operation since it's just a subtraction and division of values stored within the index object:

```
return max(0, -(-(self._stop - self._start) // self._step))
```

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/indexes/range.py#L458

I suspect that if you tested with a non-`RangeIndex`, the difference in times would be much more similar. I'll probably try modifying what you have to see if that's the case.

EDIT: After a quick check, the speed difference still seems to hold even with a standard `Index`, so there must still be some other optimization there.