# Optimizing groupby.apply with own function

Tags: python, pandas

Let me start with a litle bit of context.

I have `Spheres`, a large pandas DataFrame with positions and radius of multiple spheres during time.

The spheres are grouped using a label. Multiple spheres can share the same label, and the same sphere can have multiple label through time.

Moreover, those spheres can overlap each other, and I would like to quantify that for each group.

So I wrote a function `compute_cov` that compute some representative quantity, that I can use with :

```
Spheres.groupby(by=["Time", "Label"]).apply(compute_cov)
```

The problem I'm facing, is that this is too slow for what I need (real data is about 1000x larger, this is already taking 1.3s).

According to cProfile, around 82% of the time is spent inside groupby, and on the 13% time spent inside compute_cov, 10% alone are spent by `group.values`

I already found that if I turn the "Time" index into its own column and sort:

```
Spheres = Spheres.reset_index(0).sort_values(["Time",'Label'])
```

groubpby is much faster (~5x, now it take 258ms). So now the main problem is `group.values` which now take 65% of the time.

Any idea on how I can make it faster ?

```
def compute_cov(group):
    """
    Each group contains a number of spheres (x,y,z,r),
    I want to compute the mean coverage
    """

    n = len(group)

    # if only one sphere, no coverage
    if n == 1:
        return 0.

    # this statement alone cost 65% !
    data = group.values

    # behind c_cov is a cython implementation of what is presented bellow
    # the cython code is invisible to cProfile, so it's fast enough
    return c_cov(data)

    # for two different spheres in the group
    X1, X2 = np.triu_indices_from(data.T, k=1)

    # renaming things for readability
    _, x1, y1, z1, r1 = data[X1].T
    _, x2, y2, z2, r2 = data[X2].T

    # my definition of coverage
    cov = 1 - np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1-z2)**2) / (r1+r2)

    # ignoring negative values (no contact)
    cov = cov[cov > 0]

    # Averaging
    if cov.size > 0:
        res = cov.mean()
    else:
        res = 0

    return res
```

And Spheres looks like that:

```
              Label          Posx          Posy          Posz        Radius
Time     Num                                                               
0.000000 0        0  3.386984e-07  1.589845e-07  3.156847e-07  6.025496e-09
         1        1  3.675054e-07  7.963736e-08  1.351358e-07  5.888543e-09
         2        2  1.119772e-07  2.233176e-07  1.924494e-07  5.380718e-09
         3        3  1.470528e-07  2.069633e-07  3.838650e-07  6.802969e-09
         4        4  2.562696e-07  2.891584e-07  5.708315e-08  5.312195e-09
         5        5  6.571124e-09  9.791307e-08  5.532111e-08  6.053221e-09
         6        6  6.316083e-08  1.616296e-07  5.232142e-08  3.797439e-09
         7        7  4.026887e-07  8.798422e-08  2.067745e-07  6.237204e-09
         8        8  2.469688e-07  1.193369e-07  2.570115e-07  5.068430e-09
         9        9  1.989743e-07  3.921473e-07  1.179200e-07  5.902088e-09
         10      10  2.123426e-07  3.103694e-07  1.613411e-07  6.586051e-09
         11      11  1.142105e-07  1.420838e-07  3.256118e-07  6.831307e-09
         12      12  2.811991e-08  3.826949e-07  2.120404e-07  3.686755e-09
         13      13  7.748568e-08  2.673616e-07  3.588726e-07  4.584994e-09
         14      14  2.586889e-08  8.071737e-09  1.845098e-07  3.554399e-09
         15      15  9.605596e-08  3.912842e-07  3.637002e-07  6.306579e-09
         16      16  1.074989e-07  2.175894e-07  1.512543e-07  5.854575e-09
         17      17  2.066144e-07  2.691743e-07  2.143024e-07  3.376725e-09
         18      18  1.764215e-07  3.756435e-07  3.752302e-07  5.698067e-09
         19      19  1.146050e-07  2.977196e-07  2.579897e-07  4.599236e-09
         20      20  2.772923e-07  6.690789e-08  1.774159e-07  6.499418e-09
         21      21  3.342694e-07  1.331663e-07  9.230217e-08  6.600707e-09
         22      22  1.412380e-07  2.768119e-07  3.855737e-07  5.256329e-09
         23      23  2.649739e-07  3.461516e-07  1.771964e-07  6.882931e-09
         24      24  1.606187e-07  3.284507e-07  2.758237e-07  6.752818e-09
         25      25  1.945027e-07  8.700385e-08  3.830679e-07  6.842569e-09
         26      26  5.952504e-08  3.551758e-07  2.584339e-07  4.812374e-09
         27      27  2.497732e-07  1.133013e-07  3.168550e-07  4.469074e-09
         28      28  1.802092e-07  9.114862e-08  7.559878e-08  4.379245e-09
         29      29  2.243149e-07  1.679009e-07  6.837240e-08  6.714596e-09
...             ...           ...           ...           ...           ...
0.000003 70       0  1.278495e-07  2.375712e-07  1.663126e-08  4.536631e-09
         71       1  3.660745e-07  1.562219e-07  1.063525e-07  6.830331e-09
         72       0  6.141226e-08  2.245705e-07 -3.504173e-08  5.570172e-09
         73       0  6.176349e-08  1.768351e-07 -1.878997e-08  6.803737e-09
         74       0  3.724008e-08  1.716644e-07 -2.092554e-08  5.136516e-09
         75       0  1.314168e-07  2.360284e-07  2.691397e-08  6.456112e-09
         76       0  5.845132e-08  2.155723e-07 -3.202164e-08  4.372447e-09
         77       0  6.260762e-08  1.898116e-07 -2.036060e-08  6.294658e-09
         78       0  5.870803e-08  1.600778e-07 -2.961800e-08  5.564551e-09
         79       0  9.130520e-08  2.381047e-07 -3.473163e-08  4.978849e-09
         80       1  3.959347e-07  1.558427e-07  1.019283e-07  4.214814e-09
         81       0  8.323550e-08  2.358459e-07 -3.005664e-08  4.616857e-09
         82       0  1.232102e-07  2.407576e-07  3.397732e-08  5.359298e-09
         83       0  5.662502e-08  2.118005e-07 -2.063705e-08  4.546367e-09
         84       0  1.135318e-07  2.240874e-07 -2.560423e-08  4.328089e-09
         85       0  7.204258e-08  2.010134e-07 -3.487838e-08  5.439786e-09
         86       0  1.278136e-07  2.104107e-07  2.828027e-10  3.712955e-09
         87       0  1.202827e-07  2.116802e-07 -1.142444e-08  4.347568e-09
         88       1  3.469586e-07  1.382176e-07  9.114768e-08  3.994887e-09
         89       1  3.763531e-07  1.490025e-07  9.602604e-08  4.169581e-09
         90       1  3.528888e-07  1.445890e-07  9.125105e-08  4.709859e-09
         91       0  1.327863e-07  1.984836e-07 -1.740811e-08  5.412026e-09
         92       0  7.726591e-08  1.933702e-07 -3.621201e-08  3.913367e-09
         93       0  1.122231e-07  2.435780e-07 -2.710722e-08  5.915332e-09
         94       0  1.085695e-07  2.327729e-07 -2.492152e-08  5.698270e-09
         95       0  1.369983e-07  2.549795e-07 -6.333421e-08  5.649468e-09
         96       0  1.430033e-07  1.995499e-07 -9.115494e-09  3.726830e-09
         97       0  9.940096e-08  2.317013e-07  2.647245e-09  5.472444e-09
         98       1  3.593535e-07  1.451526e-07  9.626210e-08  3.488982e-09
         99       0  1.526954e-07  2.533845e-07 -4.934458e-08  4.841371e-09

[9900 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: This question should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you need to optimize not troubleshoot code. Folks there are very helpful and don't get quite as many questions as SO.

Comment: Good Idea, will try.

Comment: [There](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193333/average-coverage-between-each-sphere-of-each-spheres-groups) it is

Answer (score 2):

Your dataframe is of mixed `dtype` and therefore I expect `group.values` to be expensive.

[See An Old Question Of Mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008334/2336654)

Instead, grab `x`, `y`, `z`, `r` directly from the dataframe
Notice that I removed the `c_cov` call.  I have no idea what you were doing there.  You'll have to fix that yourself.

```
def compute_cov(group):
    n = len(group)

    # if only one sphere, no coverage
    if n == 1:
        return 0.

    x = group.Posx.values
    y = group.Posy.values
    z = group.Posz.values
    r = group.Radius.values    

    # for two different spheres in the group
    X1, X2 = np.triu_indices_from(n, k=1)

    # renaming things for readability
    x1, y1, z1, r1 = x[X1], y[X1], z[X1], r[X1]
    x2, y2, z2, r2 = x[X2], y[X2], z[X2], r[X2]

    # my definition of coverage
    cov = 1 - np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1-z2)**2) / (r1+r2)

    # ignoring negative values (no contact)
    cov = cov[cov > 0]

    # Averaging
    if cov.size > 0:
        res = cov.mean()
    else:
        res = 0

    return res
```

Comment: Good idea, but sadly, it have almost no effect..., I'm currently considering switching to dask which seems to be faster, but I haven't succeeded yet